# Plesk Obsidian - docker domain proxy not working

Tags: node.js, docker, plesk

I have a problem with my Plesk server. I am using  Plesk Obsidian 18.0.28 on Ubuntu Server.

I have a custom nodejs api inside a container up and running.
If I type `domain.tld:3000`, I get "**ok**" as response as expected and my api is accessible.

I added a proxy rule to proxy `api.domain.tld` to the running docker container, but when I visit the domain, I get an **403 Error** as response.

Do I need to make some settings changes anywhere in plesk to get this to work? This does not work
with other containers either.

I appreciate every helpful hint I can get.

Answer (score 1):

**I found the error:**
nginx was not installed & plesk installer was crashed
If I clicked on tools & settings => plesk => updates & upgrades the page was loading forever. Normally you can install nginx there.

Solution:

- Log into your terminal (e.g. via putty)
- Install nginx reverse proxy with: `plesk installer --select-release-current --install-component nginx`
- If you get an error message, that an installer is already running, you can force that plesk installer to stop with: `plesk installer stop`
- After you installed nginx, you just need to start it once manually.

For more information, see here: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213944825-How-to-install-and-enable-nginx-reverse-proxy-on-a-Plesk-for-Linux-server

and here: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213917525-Unable-to-open-the-Updates-and-Upgrades-page-or-start-Plesk-Installer-in-CLI-Update-operation-was-locked-by-another-update-process

But I'm still confused why I got no error message at all when trying to use proxy rules without nginx.